# EXT js Button menu item disable

Tags: button, extjs, menu, hide

I have a extjs button "Order" with menu items 'orderInsuranceMenu' for the button. I need to hide the menu items depeniding on some condition. How can i achive it

```
orderInsuranceMenu = {
    id: 'menu-order-insurance'
    ,items: [
          { 
            id:'btnMenu1',
            text: 'Test Buton1',
            iconCls: 'icon-cls',
            listeners: {
                click: function(b,e){  
                   //some code goes here
                }
            }
        }
        ,{
            id:'btnMenu2',
            text: 'Test Buton2',
            iconCls: 'icon-first-title',
            listeners: {
                click: function(b,e){  
                    //Some code here
                }
            }
        }

    ]
};



Order = new Ext.Button({
    text: 'Order&#160;'
    , iconCls: 'icon-go'
    , disabled: true
    , menu: orderInsuranceMenu
    , handler: function() {
    }

});
```

I have tried this code but it doesnt work:

Ext.getCmp('btnMenu2').hide();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Soloution:**

In Extjs 2.2 there is no method to show or hide menu item by using isVisible
So after lot of digging and checking in firebug the final soloution I found was to hide or show the specific item as shown below

```
extManager.orderInsuranceMenu.items.items[1].hide();
orderInsuranceMenu.items.items[1].show();
```

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this with the method [setDisabled](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#/api/Ext.button.Button-method-setDisabled) for the button. I.e:

```
Ext.getCmp('btnMenu2').setDisabled(true);
```

If you want to apply this for all items in your menu you can do this:

```
Ext.getCmp('menu-order-insurance').items.each(function(item) {
    if (item.isXType('button')) {
        item.setDisabled(true); // your condition here
    }
});
```

Comment: I Actualay want to hide the button.I tried to diable by using the above code even then its not working.

Comment: I am actualy using the EXT 2.2

Comment: To hide something you can use the method .setVisible([bool]) for the button. However I'm unsure how you create the menu in the above example. What is 'extManager'? And where are you running the logic to set the button visible? Have it been created at the moment you try to access it etc?

Comment: @Jemsworld Don't think there's any related changes between 2.2 and 4.0 for this code.

Comment: extManager is the namespace used in our project.  Actually i have removed the extmanager while declaring and forgot to remove at menu.  Consider it as menu: orderInsuranceMenu.   The code is able to dislay the Button with menu items.  But i am unable to hide the menu items.  As you have given setVisible/setDisable function is not available in extmanager 2.2.  Here is the API link http://www.senchaexperts.com/api/extjs2.2/  Can you please provide any other soloution to hide the menu items would be very helpfull

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `setVisible` method available in 2.2, in menu items. https://i.stack.imgur.com/kdw7f.png

If for some reason that does not work, I would resort to removing the item from the menu, and then adding it back into the menu when it is needed.